# In InstallShield Basic MSI SQL Login dialog's Server drop down list shows #TEMP0004

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

In my MSI package, I have a SQL Login dialog with a dropdownlist for SQL servers and a Browse button.

This is a standard SQL Login dialog I have not done any coding for.

When I try to install my MSI package on a system where SQL Server is not present, it shows #TEMP0004 in dropdownlist. I have searched a lot but didn't find anything except this link

[InstallShield forum thread](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=191979)

If I launch my MSI package on a system where SQL Server is installed this does not happen. But in either case, when I click the Browse button, it shows a list of all servers in the network.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Most likely its the default value. It;s not changed to something valid because no SQL Server version is found. Did you try the approach from the thread you mentioned?

Comment: Yes i did try.. but it does not worked. still looking for clue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ComboBox table there was one entry set for property IS_SQLSERVER_SERVER.
Here "TestValue" was getting assigned to IS_SQLSERVER_SERVER property. 
Removing this entry from ComboBox table fixed the problem.

Thanks